# My code is not giving proper out put on offline compilers?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, codeblocks

I am pretty new to the coding but there is some problem i am experiencing with all my compilers and IDEs. Whenever i try to compile my c code in vs code or code blocks it does not give proper or to be specific desired output which i get perfectly when i use the same code on online compilers.
for example,`the below code prints Hello and exits in VS Code but in online compiler it executes exactly the same way it should. I dont know if its a compiler problem or an IDE thing but if anybody knows this, please answer. I only encounter this with c language codes, in c++ it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{

  int info;

  struct node *next;

} node;

typedef struct
{

  node *front;

  node *rear;

} queue;

void
createqueue (queue * q)
{

  q->front = q->rear = NULL;

}

int
isempty (queue * q)
{

  if (q->front == NULL)

    return 1;

  return 0;

}


void
enqueue (queue * q, int val)
{

  node *p = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));

  p->info = val;

  p->next = NULL;

  if (isempty (q))

    q->front = q->rear = p;

  else
    {

      q->rear->next = p;

      q->rear = p;

    }

}


int
dequeue (queue * q)
{

  int t;

  t = (q->front)->info;

  node *p = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));

  p = q->front;

  if (q->front == q->rear)

    q->front = q->rear = NULL;

  else

    q->front = (q->front)->next;

  free (p);

  return t;

}


int
queuefront (queue * q)
{

  int t;

  t = q->front->info;

  return t;

}


void
traverse (queue * q)
{

  node *p = (node *) malloc (sizeof (node));

  printf ("\n Queue is: ");
  p = q->front;

  while (p != NULL)
    {

      printf ("=>%d ", p->info);

      p = p->next;

    }

}


int
main ()
{


  int choice, info, d, val;

  queue *q;

  printf ("hello\n");

  createqueue (q);


  do

    {

      printf ("\n MENU \n");

      printf ("\n 1.ENQUEUE \n");

      printf ("\n 2.DEQUEUE \n");

      printf ("\n 3.FRONT \n");

      printf ("\n 4.TRAVERSE \n");

      printf ("\n 5.EXIT \n");

      printf ("\n ENTER YOUR CHOICE: ");

      scanf ("%d", &choice);


      switch (choice)

    {

    case 1:

      printf ("enter the value");

      scanf ("%d", &val);

      enqueue (q, val);

      break;


    case 2:

      if (isempty (q))

        {

          printf ("Queue is empty");

          break;

        }

      info = dequeue (q);

      printf ("%d ", info);

      break;

    case 3:

      if (isempty (q))

        {

          printf ("Queue is empty");

          break;

        }

      d = queuefront (q);

      printf ("front= %d \n", d);

      break;

    case 4:

      if (isempty (q))

        {

          printf ("Queue is empty");

          break;

        }

      traverse (q);

      break;

    case 5:

      exit (0);

      break;

    }

    }
  while (choice > 0 && choice < 5);

  return 0;

}
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queue *q;         // uninitialized pointer
createqueue (q);  // function tries to dereference it.
```

You must make `q` point *somewhere*.

You should also learn how to use your IDE to debug -- the debugger would tell you *immediately* why your program exits (actually it doesn't exit, it crashes).

Comment: Perhaps, `queue q; createqueue(&q);`.

Comment: But still the program ran successfully on online compilers as well as my friend's VS code. Please try it running it at both online and offline compilers and maybe then you will find the problem.
However your suggestion helped me run the program successfully. Thanks for that BTW.

Comment: @Devesh2405 The _only_ way for your program to run successfully is if `q` happens to point to some writable memory by chance, and in that case your program corrupts that memory. See https://medium.com/@Magical_Mudit/programming-by-coincidence-1396e4729d8b

Comment: @EmployedRussian I understand what you want to say but to be clear `q` is pointing towards `struct queue`. So it should not require another object. but even though if you are right about that the online compiler should show the same error my offline compiler experiences.
I don't mean that you are wrong but still can you explain the reason for that happening 'cause that is something I encounter frequently.

Comment: @Devesh2405 An uninitialized pointer _does not_ point to a `struct queue`. Where it points is _undefined_. It may point to a random memory somewhere, or it may point _nowhere_ at all (e.g. be a `NULL` pointer). The reason for crash is _exactly_ that.

Comment: `Got that- Sensei`